# inserting variable with special characters

Tags: bash, shell

The following works in my shell script provided there are not special characters like ' or \ /

```
mysql -e" insert into test.mycron values ('$myhost', '$myfile')"
```

How do I make it save the entire variable "$myfile" along with special characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to escape those characters, for example with sed, something like:

```
myhost="$(echo "$myhost" | sed 's/\(['"'"'\]\)/\\&/g')"
```